# Violación invariante: argumento no válido pasado como devolución de llamada. Se esperaba una función. En su lugar recibió: falso

Tags: react-native

Para cambiar una contraseña , usé este código:

```
    onEnterText = (newPassword, value) => {
    AsyncStorage.setItem('newPassword ', 0);
    this.setState({ 'newPassword ': value });
    if (newPassword.trim() > 0) {
      this.setState({ newPassword: newPassword, ErrorStatus: true },
        this.props.navigation.navigate('Ingrese su nueva contraseña'));
      return newPassword
    }
    else {
      this.setState({ newPassword: newPassword, ErrorStatus: false });

    }


   buttonClickListener = () => {
   const { newPassword } = this.state;
   if (newPassword == "") {
   Alert.alert("Ingrese su nueva contraseña");
    }}
```

Cuando agregó la nueva contraseña y le doy clic en Confirmar:

```
return (
<TextInput style={styles.textInput}
placeholder="Nueva contraseña"
secureTextEntry
onChangeText={newPassword =>this.onEnterText(newPassword)}/>
```

En caso de que el usuario le de Confirmar ,sin haber agregado su nueva contraseña  , le mostrara un mensaje:

```
{this.state.ErrorStatus == false ?(<Text style 
{styles.errorMessage}>Escriba su nueva contraseña</Text>) : null}
```

Al darle clic en Confirmar debe de ir  `buttonClickListener`  , pero me muestra error:

```
<IconButton
iconNameButton={'contact'}
title={'Confirmar'}
style={{ marginBottom: 10 }}
onPress={this.buttonClickListener}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

el error te dice la solución, tu le estas pasando el metodo que tiene que ejecutar cuando haces click en confirmar pero aparte necesitas pasarle una función, si no quieres pasarla o no necesitas pasarle ningún dato puedes generar la funciona vacía y el resultado seria el siguiente en tu IconButton.

```
<IconButton
  iconNameButton={'contact'}
  title={'Confirmar'}
  style={{ marginBottom: 10 }}
  onPress={() => this.buttonClickListener}
/>
```

Si por algún motivo te diera error también pone () al final.
Ejemplo: onPress={() => this.buttonClickListener()}

Espero haberte ayudado.